# How do I reference a styled-component that is a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

This is the most basic example I could think of:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  css,
} from 'styled-components';

const Foo = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  const {
    children,
  } = props;

  return <div {...props}>{children}</div>;
};

export default () => {
  return <div
    css={css`
      ${Foo} {
        background: #f00;
      }
    `}
  >
    <Foo>FOO</Foo>
  </div>;
};
```

In this example, I want to style `Foo` component that is a descendent of `div`.

I would expect the resulting markup to look something like:

```html
<div class="test__Foo-wusfqk-0 hNfawX">FOO</div>
```

However, instead it is simply:

```html
<div>FOO</div>
```

It seems like no styling is applied anywhere.

Furthermore, the component `Foo` is rendered only once, but it is invoked twice, with different parameters:

```
{children: {…}, theme: {…}}
  children: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
  theme: {}

{children: "FOO"}
```

I should mention that I tried:

```js
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import styled, {
  css,
} from 'styled-components';

const Foo = styled((props) => {
  const {
    className,
    children,
  } = props;

  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>;
});

export default () => {
  return <div
    css={css`
      ${Foo} {
        background: #f00;
      }
    `}
  >
    <Foo>FOO</Foo>
  </div>;
};
```

However, when executing this code in [next.js](/questions/tagged/next.js) I am getting the following error:

> The component Styled(Component) with the id of "sc-dlnjPT" has been created dynamically.
>
> You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
>
> To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.
>
> The component Styled(Component) with the id of "sc-hKFyIo" has been created dynamically.
>
> You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
>
> To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.
>
> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

which does not make much sense given the subject code snippet.

Comment: did you try using `styled`?

Comment: Just added a comment about using `styled`.

Comment: Can you post this as a code sandbox.

Comment: Sure thing https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-07d02?file=/index.js

Comment: Just a heads up, `styled-components` appears to be mostly dead. I've used it for years and years until v5 where everything just began to break with no fixes. As a result, I've jumped ship to `@emotion/styled`. It's very similar to styled-components, but it... just works. Also, it works [without a custom nextjs _document page](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17626)!

Comment: Fixed my issue with error message:
`PreOnboardingTitle is not a styled component and cannot be referred to via component selector.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue is that `<Foo />` is not a styled component its a functional component

I think you would need to do

```
const Foo = styled.div`
    background: #f00;
`
```

Then you can change the style of `Foo` using `css` and the `$` refrence

The reason your code does not work is the following

This behaviour is only supported within the context of Styled Components: attempting to mount B in the following example will fail because component Foo is an instance of React.Component not a Styled Component.

```
const Foo = () => <div> </div>

const B = styled.div`
  ${Foo} {
  }
`
```

However, wrapping Foo in a styled() factory makes it eligible for interpolation -- just make sure the wrapped component passes along className.

```
const Foo = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  const {
    children,
  } = props;

  return <div className="Test-Class" {...props}>{children}</div>;
};

const StyledFoo = styled(Foo)``

const Main = styled.div`
  ${StyledFoo} {
    background: #f00;
  }
`
```

Code Sandbox

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Foo = (props) => {
  const { className, children } = props;

  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>;
};

const Bar = styled(Foo)``;

const Main = styled.div`
  ${Bar} {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
`;
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Main>
      {" "}
      <Bar>Hello </Bar>{" "}
    </Main>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-5s201?file=/index.js

Comment: The question is specifically about using functional component, not a styled component. According to the documentation, the above example should work. https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced (see `className` references).

Comment: @Gajus you need to look towards the end of the docs, it explains why you cant reference a functional or class component in a styled component css

Comment: You are right, and my question already includes an example of wrapping component using `styled(Foo)` and shows that it does not work as expected.

Comment: Your last example does not use `StyledFoo` as a selector. If it did, it would fail.

Comment: Why cant you use it as a selector? Does it throw an error, or just show no styles?

Comment: If you have time do you think you can make a code sandbox please?

Comment: Sure thing https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-07d02?file=/index.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-5s201?file=/index.js

Comment: I am not sure that you linked, but it doesn't render anything. It is just `Bar` text. You code implies that you tried applying styles to it. https://imgur.com/a/ovv6flN

Comment: yes sorry please check again, was editing in a different fork.

Comment: This does indeed work. Thank you for helping me to figure it out.

Comment: Absolutely it was an interesting problem. Have fun coding! Also feel free to propose edits to the answer. Im going to remove some unnecessary text from it right now.

Comment: @Gajus Your original codesandbox is just missing the template literal as a second argument to `styled`: const Foo = styled(() => {})``.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Wow hahahahahah thats crazy, you're right

Comment: Indeed @MattCarlotta. I have not noticed reading the original docs that there is `` at the end of it. Thus the confusion. The documentation does already correctly say how to do it.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the `css` helper is only designed for generating styles based upon strings, CSSProperties, or an interpolated function with `props`. It's not designed for component selectors. Instead, as Omar mentioned, it should be only be used in a `styled` context.